# How to execute function in phantomjs asynchronously

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, phantomjs

I am unable to get console messaged logged inside  `page.evaluateAsync` method.

```
 page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
      console.log('The web page said: ' + msg);
    };


 page.open('/Users/somenamr/Desktop/test/test.html', function(status) {
        if (status == 'success') {

            page.evaluateAsync(function() {
       console.log('This is not getting logged. Hi! I\'m evaluateAsync call!');
    }, 1000);

            var html = page.evaluate(function(s) {

    window.console.log = function(msg) { alert(msg) }; 
             function doProcessingOnWebPage(node)
             { 
                 console.log("this i am getting");
             }});}});
```

Whereas i am getting logs which are inside the page.evaluate method.
page. evaluateAsync is getting executed byphantomjs or not?
If not is there any other way to call functions asynchronously? 
I have also tried setTimeout but no logs from it also coming.

Comment: Getting them logged to which console, that of the headless browser?

Comment: yes, I am calling phantomjs exe as out proc . I have also set up page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
  console.log('The web page said: ' + msg);
};